# Utility method that allows passing a different comparison function in java for using in contains

Tags: java, collections, comparison

I have a class that represents each row in my database table. So it has some data members that represent the primary keys in the table while others are non key columns. Say I have a list of rows (listA) that I fetched at some point of time, then after some duration I fetch some more rows (listB) which can contain ones that were fetched earlier but having some updated data in the non key columns. I want to merge listA and listB retaining updated values (i.e stuff in listB). This comparison requires only checking the key columns. So are there any utility (maybe in guava or apache commons etc) contains / removeAll methods that take in a custom comparison function?
For all other purposes I want to check all the data members in the class for equality. 
Please note the usual removeAll will use the equals and hashcode that which has been overridden to compare every data member in the class, I want to use a different comparator that compares only the data members that are part of the primary key for the contains.

Comment: You may want to check my revised answer

Comment: If using Java 8, you can use streams and predicates to determine if an element is already in your list. Depending on the size of your results, this might be slow, as you have to scan your list for each new element. Maybe another option is to keep in parallel to your list of results a Map of your primary keys to their corresponding elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard-Java Set operations. If your "row" class does *not* implement `equals` and `hashCode` using *only* the primary key information, you can use some wrapper or utility class that does, for example:

```
class Row {

  Object pk, a, b;

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    // Checks for other's type, etc.
    Row otherRow = (Row) other;
    return pk.equals(otherRow.pk) && a.equals(otherRow.a) && b.equals(otherRow.b);
  }
}

class PkInfo {

  final Row row;

  PkInfo(Row row) {
    this.row = row;
  }

  Row getRow() {
    return row;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    // Checks for other's type, etc.
    PkInfo otherPkInfo = (PkInfo) other;
    return row.pk.equals(otherPkInfo.row.pk);
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return row.pk.hashCode();
  }
}
```

So, whenever you want to merge result sets, you can do something like:

```
// Your result sets
Collection<Row> listA, listB;

// Your primary-key-based sets
Set<PkInfo> pkiA = new HashSet<PkInfo>();
for (Row r : listA)
  pkiA.add(new PkInfo(r));
Set<PkInfo> pkiB = new HashSet<PkInfo>();
for (Row r : listB)
  pkiB.add(new PkInfo(r));

// Remove from A the rows present in B
pkiA.removeAll(pkiB);

// Modify listA
listA = new ...();
for (PkInfo pki : pkiA)
  listA.add(pki.getRow());

// Add all from listB
listA.addAll(listB);
```

You can place the code above in a utility method that you call whenever you want to update a list with fresh data from another.

Comment: removeAll will use the equals and hashcode that compares every data member in the class, I want to use a different comparator that compares only the data members that are part of the primary key

Comment: You cannot use a Set with other equals / hashCode semantics than the ones you created it with, you have to do some kind of "translation" to use PK-only semantics. Check my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your class you just need to @Override the public boolean equals(Object obj). That is the method used by List when you are testing the contains(Object).